# How to get session token when authenticating to JSON REST API (in R)

Tags: r, authentication, session, token, httr

I'm trying to access JSON data (in **R**) from a REST API.

To authenticate myself, I need to use a POST method in https://dashboard.server.eu/login. The data that needs to be sent are email and password:

```
library(httr)

login <- list(
  email = "my@email.com",
  password = "mypass"
)

res <- POST("https://dashboard.server.eu/login", body = login, encode = "form", verbose())
```

When executing the above, I get this output:

```
-> POST /login HTTP/1.1
-> Host: dashboard.server.eu
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.59.0 r-curl/3.3 httr/1.4.1
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Cookie: session=10kq9qv1udf0107F4C70RY14fsum41sq50
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
-> Content-Length: 53
-> 
>> email=my%40email.com&password=mypass

<- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<- access-control-allow-headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, If-None-Match
<- access-control-allow-methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
<- cache-control: no-cache
<- content-encoding: gzip
<- content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
<- date: Mon, 09 Mar 2020 14:58:31 GMT
<- set-cookie: session=10kq9qv1udf0107F4C70RY14fsum41sq50; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict; Path=/
<- vary: origin,accept-encoding
<- x-microserv: NS4yNi4xODQuMjE3
<- x-poweredby: Poetry
<- Content-Length: 2346
<- Connection: keep-alive
```

The doc of the site says that, in case of success, a JSON `res` is returned and contains a string token in `res.data._id`.

[image]

I don't find it... even looking at every list (and sub-lists) of `res`.

How am I supposed to find the token?

Following the doc, and an example in **AngularJS**, I'm then supposed to do:

```
// Create JSON Object with your token
let authorizeObject = {
    'Authorization': 'Session ' + token,
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'accept': 'application/json,text/plain',
};

// Create header from the previous JSON Object
let header = {'headers':authorizeObject};

// Use the header in your http request...
$http.get('https://dashboard.server.eu/', header)
```

Any hint on making this dream become true?

**UPDATE --** With cURL, I could check that there is a `_id` key/value returned…

With the command:

```
curl -k -X POST "https://dashboard.server.eu/login" \
             -d '{ "email" : "my@email.com", "password" : "mypass" }' \
             -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I get the output:

```
{
  "_id": "697v2on4ll0107F4C70RYhosfgtmhfug",
  "isAuthenticated": true,
  "user": {
    "_id": "5dd57868d83cfc000ebbb273",
    "firstName": "me",
    "lastName": "Me",
...
```

So, the session token is indeed somewhere...

Does this help to help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the image of `res` in your question, the message *is* there, under `content` - it's just that the content is stored as a vector of raw bytes, which is why you didn't recognise it as json.

Since any file type can be sent by http, the contents in an `httr` response object are stored in raw format rather than a character string for various reasons - perhaps most importantly because many binary files will contain a `0x00` byte, which isn't allowed in a character string in R.

In your case, we can not only tell that `res$content` *is* text, but that it is your "missing" json. The first six bytes of `res$content` are shown in your image, and are `7b, 22, 5f, 69, 64, 22`. We can convert these to a character string in R by doing:

```
rawToChar(as.raw(c(0x7b, 0x22, 0x5f, 0x69, 0x64, 0x22)))
[1] "{\"_id\""
```

This matches the first six characters of your expected json string.

Therefore if you do:

```r
httr::content(res, "text")
```

or

```r
rawToChar(res$content)
```

You will get your json as a character string.

Comment: Dear @Allan, will come back to you tomorrow. Need to check. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!